# Open browser inside iPhone App is authorised or not ?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

We are creating one app in which we need to open website on browser inside my application. Is it acceptable by AppStore . Please help me to solve this query.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @chaaruu its better if you can tell us whether anyone of the answer is helpful for you or not. It will help us to improve or give new answers.

Answer (score 2):

Its acceptable. You can use UIWebView to show a website.

Answer (score 1):

App Store Review Guidelines, 2.12:

> Apps that are not very useful, are simply web sites bundled as apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

Answer (score 0):

It's acceptable.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]
```

Comment: This doesn't open a website or browser inside an app.

Comment: As Naga Mallesh Maddali added, you can use UIWebView. It's totally acceptable.